# Why Single Epsilon value is 1.401298E-45

Tags: c#, floating-point

I don't understand why Single epsilon value is 1.401298E-45 and not 1E-126, if internally has an exponent of -126 and a mantissa of 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest positive `Single` value has an exponent of −126 with a base of two and a binary significand of .00000000000000000000001 (2<sup>−23</sup>), so its value is 2<sup>−149</sup>, which is approximately 1.4• 10<sup>−45</sup>.

Comment: I forgot that we were in base 2!  I asume that the implicit leading bit of the significand is not added.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that IEEE-754 single-precision floats are stored in base 2-representation. This is how the smallest possible positive denormal value for single-precision is laid out:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 00000000 00000000000000000000001
             Hex: 0000 0001
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -126 (Stored: 0, Bias: 126)
       Hex-float: +0x1p-149
```

In other words, `126+23 = 149`, so its value is `2^-149`, which is roughly `1.4E-45`.