# Why does float.TryParse() accepts "1.000e-45" and rounds it to 1.401298E-45?

Tags: c#, floating-point, .net-framework-version, tryparse

I try to validate that an input string is a float. To achieve this I pass the input string like "1.000e-45" which is closer to 0 than the c# float minimum allows (1.401298E-45). I expect float.tryParse to return false. Instead it returns true and the parsed number is rounded up to the float minimum (1.401298E-45). If the string contains an even lower number, float.TryParse() seems to round down to 0.

Do I miss something?

What could I do to validate that low numbers like this are not interpreted as float?

```
var isFloat = float.TryParse("1.000e-45", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var number);
```

**Update:** the user input MUST be a float in a string. it is not allowed to be of higher precision because of a specification. Just imagine it as some kind of API which gives me a string which should be a float value. I have to validate that it is in the ranges of a float.

**Update 2:** this is not a question about float precision. I know that you cannot have 100% precision because of the binary aspect and the size of the mantisse. As i stated in the question, i know the most close value to 0 for a float. I just didnt expect TryParse() to do rounding like this when its close to 0. I expected it to fail.

**Update 3:** I hope this makes it more clear. That is the specification that i have to follow.

- The input is a string. the string represents a number. like "3.45e12"
- the number is not allowed to be outside of the range of "±3.4028235e+38".
- the number is not allowed to be smaller in magnitute than "±1.401298e-45".  That is what the specification says."0" is allowed too, but not something like "1e-100" or "1e-46".
- What i want to do is validate that the user input (a string) fullfills this specification. I dont have to convert the string number into a c# number type and calculate with it. I just have to validate the input string number and then i send the string number to an API. This api would have problems when the string does not match the specification.
- I tried to use float.TryParse() for this validation. It works for the min/max ranges (.Net Framework). But it seems to be the wrong approach. float.TryParse() will always return true for number strings that are closer to 0 than it can actually represent and it will round the result to fit into a float: it rounds down to 0 (e.g. for "1e-46") or rounds up to 1.401298E-45 (e.g. for "1e-45". It makes sense to some point, because it does the same when it can not handle the precision of a value like "999999999999999.9" which is not above max and not too close to 0. It rounds it to 1e13.

Comment: *Do I miss something?* you miss float specification ... if you want better precission use `double`

Comment: If you expect `TryPass` to only succeed for numbers which can be represented, would you expect it to fail for `0.1` as well?

Comment: @Selvin i dont want better precision. The value has to be a float and i want to validate the user input which is a string. The user is not allowed to enter a value outside of the float ranges.

Comment: @chtz I expected tryparse to validate the ranges, which it actually does for min and max, but not for the border to 0. That is why i asked whether I missed something.

Comment: @Sinatr that is an interesting approach. What I not stated in this question is, that i will have to do something similiar for another user input field of type double. in this case i would not have a type of higher precision like double is for float, i guess.

Comment: @Sinatr No, that won't work for numbers that are close to zero like the one in the question. I think your code has a typo (i.e., you used `MinValue` twice).

Comment: So `1.401299E-45` should be valid, but `1.401297E-45` should not be? But `0.0` is supposed to be valid again?

Comment: @chtz hm good point. Especially if i would have to work on the parsed number. But i dont have to do that. I just transfer the number-strings around, but have to validate them. I get the string from an api and have to give it back to a different api. and inbetween i do a validation.

Comment: @AronCederholm no, i know that, But i had other expectations of how TryParse() works.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit hasty there. This is a legit question.

Comment: I'm not surprised TryParse works. Only thing I can thing of is you do some pattern matching before you call tryparse.

Comment: [Could this be related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556995/why-single-epsilon-value-is-1-401298e-45)  1.401298 × 10⁻⁴⁵ is the decimal equivalent of 2⁻¹⁴⁹. So when you are trying to check 1.000000 × 10⁻⁴⁵, I guess it will simply be rounded off to the nearest binary representation, which still is 1.401298 × 10⁻⁴⁵. I suppose if you go beyond the rounding range, it will start acting like you want. So, 7.000e-46 (0.7 × 10⁻⁴⁵) would return false, because it cannot be converted to a binary representation that is possible to describe with the current bit depth. Can you verify this?

Comment: The question needs to be restated clearly. First, “I try to validate that an input is a float” is impossible: A `float` is an internal data type in which a sequence of bits represents a number in a specific way. Users do not enter bits. They press keys (or other input devices) which are generally translated to characters, and the program receives characters. Those characters can form **numerals** that represent numbers, such as “3.4” for 3.4 or “.034e2” also for 3.4. So, first, the question needs to explain **which strings of characters** it wants to accept.

Comment: Follow up comment: Actually, I think 1.401298/2 × 10⁻⁴⁵ should be the breakpoint. Values greater than that are binary-wise indistinguishable from 1.401298 × 10⁻⁴⁵, while values smaller than that will fail.

Comment: Re “it is not allowed to be of higher precision because of a specification”: This does not really make sense. First, any individual numeral is generally of infinite precision: “3” represents exactly 3 and does not represent 3.00001 or 2.9999. When we speak of `float` precision, we can mean the precision of the format as a whole: How many digits (binary digits) there are in the format, so the precision with which numbers in the format can be changed. Note that any individual number in the format is infinitely precise: It represents one number exactly…

Comment: … The issue of precision arises when trying to convert numbers between formats: When a `double` is converted to a `float` or some input numeral is converted to a `float`, there is a question of how much precision is available to represent the result, causing there to be some rounding error in the conversion. So this sentence that the input “is not allowed to be of higher precision because of a specification” needs to be explained. If the user enters “0.3”, that is infinitely precise, and 0.3 cannot be exactly represented in the `float` format. So is it allowed or not? What is the exact rule?

Comment: @AronCederholm: The actual minimum positive `float` value is not 1.401298e-45 but 1.40129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125e-45, so half of it would be 7.00649232162408535461864791644958065640130970938257885878534141944895541342930300743319094181060791015625e-46.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been clearer that I cut of the digits (b/c of the comment length restriction). Thanks for the clarification. However, I don't think this is the reason. It was just quick thought from me, as 1e-100 still validates as true, which it really should. It is still a float, even if it can't be represented.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i added the specification to the question (update3). It is about validating a string which represents a number. And this string number has to fullfill the sepcification. the input string number could be something like that `"4e10"`, `"1.45e-40"` and so on.

Comment: @AronCederholm tryparse seems to work differently, it rounds down to 0 for "1e-46" or lower.  OR it rounds up to 1.401298E-45 for "1e-45". both cases it will return true. I guess tryparse just returns false for not a number and outside min max range

Comment: the more i think about it, the more i believe that i will have to parse the string myself or try out some kind of regex... or overwrite the userinput with the tryparse result to tell the user indirectly that "sorry, your input is not ok, this is the closed you can get"

Comment: `Try.Parse` is simply not designed to satisfy these specifications. Rounding is built-in, and it generally follows good and common practices. These specifications include some arbitrary restrictions, so there is no reason to expect a general-purpose routine like `Parse` to satisfy them. So, yes, you will likely have to parse it yourself. A regular expression likely will not serve. For example, you need to accept “3e38” and “30e37” but not “30e38”, so it involves processing the value of the exponent, not merely its syntactic form.

Comment: That said, the parsing is likely not to difficult: Ignore one sign, identify the first significant (non-zero) digit, determine the location of the “.” if any and the value of the exponent to establish the position value of the first significant digit, and then examine the digits to compare them to the upper and lower bounds.